# Entity Framework / ADO.NET / SQL Server

Tags: entity-framework-6

Entity Framework 6 / Multi Layered Application / Connection Pooling is spiking and ultimately crashing our application by timing out and not allowing any further Connection Acquisition. We have gone through the code and standardized our connection strings and searched for any connections not being closed. Can anyone shed light on what might be causing this? We believe the area is at the connection acquisition level where too many requests for connections at once are happening. Not sure how to further test or dig for what is actually happening.

How can I can further troubleshoot and/or find causes to this problem?

Comment: If you believe that connections are the issue, why not write data on an intermittent basis on connections in use? Or watch the connection count in SSMS?

Comment: I have traced the connections and find that it is more around SQL Scheduling. It's almost like connection requests are being queued and something is holding it up from establishing a connection. I appreciate the quick reply and also any insight. It is an interesting problem that is difficult to explain and even duplicate. The site has many moving parts and layers. It works fine for a few weeks and then out of nowhere stops establishing connections. I was hoping that I might get lucky and have someone say, "Yeah, that happens to me too!" :)